# C++ Assign to implicitly converted lvalue

Tags: c++, c++14

Consider this snippet of C++ code:

```
struct Foo {
    float value;

    operator float& () {
        return this->value;
    }
};

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    foo=1.0f;   //Doesn't compile, foo isn't implicitly converted to a float&

    return 0;
}
```

Why doesn't this compile? Is there a specific reason this wasn't included in the C++ standard? Or an equivalent does indeed exist and I'm just using it wrong?

Comment: "*Doesn't work, `foo` isn't implicitly converted to a `float&`*" You didn't tell it to convert to a `float&`, you tried to assign a `float` to it (actually a `double`, but that's beside the point). These are two different things.

Comment: @AndersK. Literally the question is asking about why it doesn't compile. So... of course it doesn't.

Comment: @AndersK. No it isn't? it's still reproducible.

Comment: @AndersK. No, and quite frankly, you're being ridiculous. Code that doesn't compile but accurately reproduces a compiler error the OP is asking about is well outside both the letter and the intent of that particular close reason.

Comment: @AndersK.: Cut it out

Comment: @Barry: I'm sorry to see your answer deleted. It highlights an important detail, which the other great answer does not, that writing `a = b` is equivalent to write `a.operator=(b)`, the reason the converting operator is not looked for.

Comment: @erenon I don't think mine adds much of anything on top of Gill's. `a = b` pretty clearly doesn't meet any of those 5 bullet points.

Comment: sometimes i write shit. sorry u all

Comment: Oops, I forgot the f after the number literal. I didn't mean to make the literal a double.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For pretty much all other operators, your conversion operator would do exactly what you want, and it would continue to do exactly what you want even if you add custom operators.

```
struct Foo {
    float value;
    operator float& () { return this->value; }
    Foo &operator+=(Foo);
};
int main() {
    Foo foo {};
    foo+=1.0; // compiles and works
    // equivalent to foo.operator float&()+=1.0;
}
```

However, `=` is special, the rules for `=` are different compared to most other operators. As identified by T.C.:

> **13.3.1.2 Operators in expressions [over.match.oper]**
>
> 4 For the built-in assignment operators, conversions of the left operand are restricted as follows:
> (4.1) -- no temporaries are introduced to hold the left operand, and
> (4.2) -- no user-defined conversions are applied to the left operand to achieve a type match with the left-most parameter of a built-in candidate.

Together with the fact that any custom `operator=` is not allowed to be defined as a global function, this makes sure that `foo=bar;` where `foo` is a class type always means `foo.operator=(bar);`, nothing else.

The fact that this one operator is singled out doesn't explain the reason, but does make it quite clear that it's an intentional decision, and making sure that `foo=bar;` always means `foo.operator=(bar);`, nothing else, by itself already seems like a valid reason.

Comment: I think "an assignment operator" means both simple assignment and compound assignment operators

Comment: What do you mean by "the built-in operator= global function"  ?

Comment: @T.C. In that section, does "built-in assignment operators" include the compound assignment operators?   And can you explain why, in hvd's code, `foo+=1.0;` is accepted but `foo.operator+=(1.0);` is rejected, when the table in that section says the former is converted to the latter for purposes of overload resolution?

Comment: @M.M There's not "simple assignment operator" and "compound assignment operator", there's "assignment operator" and "compound assignment operator", see [expr.ass].

Comment: @T.C. Thanks for that, I couldn't find anything explicit. Will edit.

Comment: @M.M As for "built-in operator= global function", for purposes of overload resolution, built-in operators are considered as if they are global functions, as described in [over.built].

Comment: Related: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#260 (handles sort of the "inverse" case).

Comment: Nice answer, I found it much clearer than Gill Bates' one since it explains that operator= is a special case. And that's nice, since I can make a type a "synonym" of another just by overloading the implicit cast operator and the operator=. I thought I needed to overload every single operator. I still disagree with the C++ standard for making the operator= a special case, but I can tolerate a single case. Many thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Implicit conversion is only done in the following cases:

> Implicit conversions are performed whenever an expression of some type
>   T1 is used in context that does not accept that type, but accepts some
>   other type T2; in particular:
>
> - when the expression is used as the argument when calling a function that is declared with T2 as parameter;
> - when the expression is used as an operand with an operator that expects T2;
> - when initializing a new object of type T2, including return statement in a function returning T2;
> - when the expression is used in a switch statement (T2 is integral type);
> - when the expression is used in an if statement or a loop (T2 is bool).

None of those is the case here. Instead the compiler is trying to find a suitable `operator=` to work with a `double`. To have this compile you need to overload that operator ( you actually want a `float` as seen in the code ):

```
Foo& operator=(float other)
{
  value = f;
  return *this;
}
```

And change your assignment to `foo = 1.0f;`

Your conversion function would work with for example:

```
float f = foo;
```

Comment: You could also `static_cast<float&>(foo) = 1.0f;` to invoke the conversion explicitly, though this defeats the purpose a tiny bit.

Comment: Uhm, you need a `return` in that assignment operator. Also I'd pass the argument by value since it's built-in type.

Comment: What I think is missing in this answer is why the global built-in `operator=` isn't found. Per [over.built]p18, the built-in operator participates in overload resolution as `float &operator=(float &, double)`. With other operators, it would be found and considered even if a member operator function is also available. For example, `foo+=1.0;` works. It continues to work even if you add `void operator+=(Foo) {}` to `Foo`: overload resolution prefers the built-in operator. It would be covered by "when the expression is used as an operand with an operator that expects T2".

Comment: @hvd: The built-in operator participates in overload resolution, but adding a `void operator+=(double) = delete;` makes the code not compile, so I wouldn't say the built-in is preferred.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf I didn't mean that the built-in operator was preferred because it's a built-in operator. I had two relevant operators in my example, a built-in operator and a user-defined operator. The built-in operator was preferred because according to the regular rules for overload resolution, it was a better match. I hope it's clearer like this.

Comment: ah. :) [[[[[[[[

Comment: That list of bullet points is just some examples, it's not supposed to be an exhaustive list.  You have to look specifically at overload resolution to find that it does not consider conversion functions in this context.

Comment: I'm near to -1 this because while you quote "when the expression is used as an operand with an operator that expects T2;", we certainly have a situation where we have a `operator=` that takes a `float&` and `double&` on the left side in overload resolution, so the question arises "why is the implicit conversion not done". +1'ed @hvd's answer

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb You're right that I should've also quoted the relevant parts of what hvd quoted but now that he did it I'll leave this answer be. OP can pick the one he likes best. Your downvote would be justified.