# Why the C++ standard explicitly says that for built-in assignment operators, no temporaries for left operand are introduced?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, assignment-operator

C++ standard explicitly says that for built-in assignment operators, no temporaries for left operand are introduced. However I do not think it is necessary. Citing from N4296 §13.3.1.2/4:

> For the built-in assignment operators, conversions of the left operand
>   are restricted as follows:
>
> (4.1) — **no temporaries are introduced to hold the left operand**, and
>
> (4.2) — no user-defined conversions are applied to the left operand to achieve a type match with the left-most
>   parameter of a built-in candidate.

I understand the second rule (see for example https://stackoverflow.com/a/39937432/6209703), but the first seems rendundant to me. All built-in operators are described in §13.6, and there are only three assignment operators (paragraphs 18, 19, 20). Their first argument is always a reference to a non-const type, and such references cannot be bound to temporaries.