# Lvalue reference operator vs assignment operator precedence

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I came across a compilation error in which I was hoping the compiler would implicitly use a custom lvalue reference operator rather than an assignment operator.

I have generated a minimum reproducible example that shows the phenomenon. Could someone explain what is happening here and potentially ways to allow the implicit lvalue reference operator to be called?

If I uncomment the assignment operator deletion this fails to compile:

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct wrapper
{
private:
    T t;
public:
    wrapper( T _t ) : t( _t ) {}
//    wrapper<T> operator=( T ) = delete;
    operator const T&() const { return t; }
    operator T&() { return t; }
};

int main()
{
    wrapper<int> w( 0 );

    std::cout << w << std::endl;
    w = 1;
    std::cout << w << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: See <https://stackoverflow.com/q/39936865>: `w = 1` *always* means `w.operator=(1)`

Answer (score 2):

But even if `operator=` is commented, `w = 1` is not calling either `operator [const] T&`. It is simply using the `wrapper(T)` constructor to make a `wrapper` out of `1`, and then the implicitly defined `operator=` to assign that value to `w`. If you `delete` `operator=`, that's clearly not possible.

The `operator T&` is being used only by the `cout` line, because it is an `operator` that can convert a `wrapper` (for which you have not overloaded `<<`) to something that `<<` can deal with, an `int`.

I guess you wanted `w = 1;` to implicitly behave as if it was `static_cast<int&>(w) = 1;`.

---

The one above, by itself, is an incomplete answer, as the whole point is probably *why doesn't `w = 1;` behave like `static_cast<int&>(w) = 1;`?* And the answer is that `operator=` is special, as suggested in the answer linked in a comment by [Artyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5754656/artyer). The relevant wording in the standard is [here](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.oper#5).